# displaying ajax response in textarea as soon as page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a continous ajax request asking for some data
    that is to be displayed in textarea.
    Now my problem, how do I display the data as soon as page is loaded.

```
My template code is as follows:




     <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquerycall/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
               var setid = 0;
               var s = new String();
               var my_array = new Array();
               var no_of_lines = 0;
               var array_copy = new Array();
               var fname ="{{fname}}"
               var pid = "{{pid}}"
               function displayfile()
               {

                var text = $("#textid").val();
                if(text == "")
                {
                         no_of_lines = 0;
                }
                else
                {

                        array_copy = text.split("\n");
                        no_of_lines = array_copy.length;


                }
                /*$("#tid").val(no_of_lines)*/
                $.ajax({
                                type:"POST",
                                url:"/displayoutput/",
                                datatype:"json",
                                data:{text:no_of_lines,filename:fname,pid:pid},
                                success:function(data)
                                        {

                                                s = data.filedata;
                                                if(s == "")
                                                {
                                                   clearInterval(setid);

                                                }
                                                my_array = s.split("\n");
                                                displaydata(my_array);

                                        }


                        });


              }

                    function displaydata(my_array)
              {

                   var i = 0;
                   var length = my_array.length;
                   for(i=0;i<my_array.length;i++)
                   {
                       var line = my_array[i] + "\n";
                       line = line.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
                       $("#textid").append(line);
                       $("#tid").val(line)

                   }


             }


              $("form").submit(function(event)
              {

                    setid = setInterval(displayfile,1000);
                    event.preventDefault();

              });

              $("#stop").click(function()
              {
                    clearInterval(setid);
              });
     });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Click Me"/><br><br>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button><br><br>
<textarea id="textid" disabled="true" readonly="true" rows=30 cols=100></textarea><br><br>


</form>
</body>
</html>



Here, the data is loaded when I click the "Click Me"
But I want the data to be loaded as soon as page is loaded
Any suggestions will be valuable
Thanks in advance
```

tazim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `displayfile();` within your `.ready()` handler.

If you don't wait to lose one second, modify your code like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event)
{
       setid = setInterval(displayfile,1000);
       event.preventDefault();
}).submit();
```

Or.. just put `displayfile();` anywhere in your ´.ready`handler to execute that ajax
request as soon as possible (after the`DOM` is ready);

If you don't need the `DOM` to be ready you can execute that function even further by creating a selfexecuting anonymous function.

```
(function(){
    // code to execute
})();
```

You can fill that with the code from your `displayfile()` function and it will execute
**asap**.

Comment: please explain it more specifically

Comment: I am not suppose to use this submit button also.
continous ajax request is sent as soon as page is loaded and
response should be shown in the textarea.
The page should contain only textarea . where requests are sent in every one second and data is loaded the interval is cleared as soon as no more data is left. I tried putting submit button just for understanding But ideally the page should contain only textarea with data getting displayed . Thanks in advance for any suggestions sample code

Answer (score 0):

tazim,

change:

```
          $("form").submit(function(event)
          {
                setid = setInterval(displayfile,1000);
                event.preventDefault();
          });
```

to:

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
                displayfile();
                setid = setInterval(displayfile,1000);
          });
```

jim